# Is it safe to use a dummy hdmi plug?

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, extended-desktop

I want to connect a "dummy hdmi plug" to my graphics card to enable a extended screen and show the contents of the extended screen on my tablet (over vnc), can I damage my graphics card if I use one of those [hdmi dummy plugs](http://www.ebay.com/itm/HDMI-dummy-plug-DDC-EDID-emulator-fake-display-headless-R9-290-290X-DVI-D-/161265341755?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item258c29d53b)?

Comment: It won't damage your hardware if that's what your asking

Comment: You should be able to do this without any hardware at all. On Windows, in the Screen Resolution control panel: click detect, for display select "available display on. . .", and for multiple displays select "try to connect anyway on: VGA".

Comment: My graphics card only has 1 dvi, 1 vga and 1 hdmi, and my monitor only works with vga, so unfortunately I can not force enable a secondary screen unless I have a device connected